# Evaluating this limit $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)} {x^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

> I need to evaluate this limit
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)} {x^2}. 
> $$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)} {x^2}  \frac{1+\cos(x^3+2x)}{1+\cos(x^3+2x)}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x^3+2x)} {x^2 (1+\cos(x^3+2x))}  
$$

and multiply and divide $ x^2(x+\frac2 x) $ , but It doesn't seem the best approach. I might evaluate it using l'Hôpital rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)} {x^2}=
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)}{(x^3+2x)^2}\frac{(x^3+2x)^2} {x^2}
$$
The first factor has limit $1/2$; the second factor has limit $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Then use l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x^3-2x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(3x^2-2)\sin(x^3-2x)}{2x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6x\sin(x^3-2x)+(3x^2-2)^2\cos(x^3-2x)}2=\frac{0+\overbrace{4}^{=(-2)^2}}{2}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Using l'Hôpitals rule seems a good idea, you get : $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(3x^2+2 )\sin(x^3+2x)} {2x}$$

Now you should be able to evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents:

$1-\cos u\sim_0 \dfrac{u^2}2$, hence
$\;\dfrac{1 - \cos(x^3+2x)} {x^2}\sim_0\dfrac{(x^3+2x)^2}{2x^2}\sim_0\dfrac{4x^2}{2x^2}=2. $